# How can I share a reused UIImageView with protocols?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm not sure if this is possible, however I have a number of custom `UITableViewCells`, all of which contain some common components.

For example, they all contain a `UIIMageView` that represents a user's avatar:

```
   fileprivate var messageAvatar: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_avatar")
        return imageView
    }()
```

Rather than repeat this in multiple places, I was thinking I could create a `Protocol` with these common, required properties and use an extension to provide the standard, default implementation for them:

```
protocol MyCustomCellProtocol: class {
    var avatar: UIImageView { get set }
}

extension MyCustomCellProtocol {
    var avatar: UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is how I can initialise these or make use of them within my custom cells.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better would be creating subclass of `UIImageView` with setting "default" properties inside `awakeFromNib`

```
class AvatarImageView: UIImageView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

then you can create your image view as `lazy` variable for your custom subclass inside classes when you need it

```
lazy var messageAvatar: AvatarImageView = {
    let imageView = AvatarImageView(frame: .zero)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "user_avatar")
    return imageView
}()
```